# Linear Gradient Border with Css Modules

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

so im trying to make linear gradient border with css modules like its shown on picutre,
i tried this and works but, it breaks on iOS.

[image: [linear border radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYFmN.png)]

```
.serviceSection {
  width: 304px !important;
  height: 375px;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 0px 24px 24px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;

  backdrop-filter: blur(96.19999694824219px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(96.19999694824219px);
}

.serviceSection::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    #ffffff60 0%,
    rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.04) 100%
  );

  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
  mask-composite: exclude;
  mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
}
```